# Python textwrap with formatting

Tags: python

Trying to use textwrap.

I am using:

```
zz = 'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat'

print(textwrap.fill(zz, 75).replace("\n"," \"\n"))
```

The output is ALMOST what I need.

```
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis "
praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas "
molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt "
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum "
fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero "
```

I just want each line to begin with quotation marks,

Comment: `'\n'.join('"%s"' % line for line in textwrap.fill(zz, 75).splitlines())`

Comment: use `replace("\n","\n\""))` instead.

Comment: @jfaccioni, that won't handle the first line

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
print('"' + textwrap.fill(zz, 75).replace("\n"," \"\n\"") + '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import textwrap

zz = 'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat'

k = '"'
zz = k+zz

f_result = textwrap.fill(zz, 75).replace('\n', '" \n "')

print(f_result+k)
```

If you don't need quotation mark in the end of line, just replace `f_result = textwrap.fill(zz, 75).replace('\n', '" \n "')`

with `f_result = textwrap.fill(zz, 75).replace('\n', '\n "')`